# HAML on Rails 3 returning "Template is missing" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have tried to render some files with HAML in Rails 3 without success.

My testfiles have the extension `.html.haml`.

In my Gemfile, I have the line `gem 'haml'` and have run `bundle install`.

When I run my app, I get the following error:

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template posts/index with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb]} in view paths "/Users/piet/Sites/blog/app/views"`

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you restart your rails process?

Comment: I renamed `yourview.html.erb` to `yourview.html.haml` and it showed `Template is Missing`. So I restarted rails server and it's working now.

Answer (score 69):

For rails 3 all you need to do is add:

gem "haml-rails"

to your Gemfile, then do a "bundle install"

See https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails

If you still seeing the error try restarting your server.

Comment: this should be marked as the answer - restarting the server was the extra step I needed.

Comment: I also needed the server restart. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3, make sure that this is close to the top of your `config/application.rb` file:

```
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

It should be right below

```
# Put this in config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
```

Comment: I've been down a rabbit hole all day thinking I had some kind of rvm/passenger/gemsets/unix permission issue because of this.  I added a new environment ('qa') at the time of Capifying and deploying to a new server.  The whole time I needed to add 'qa' to the following line `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(qa development test)))`.  Thank-you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: confirmed, exactly the same issue I had

Answer (score 1):

HAML does work without issue in Rails 3.. Two things:

1. Make sure your route file has `resources :posts`
2. Make sure you have the file app/views/posts/index.html.haml

Could you try that? And confirm that Andrew's comment about restarting Rails has been tried as well.

Comment: I don`t know why, but now it`s working ;9
Thx for your answer